# Composer require version but allow also develop branches

Tags: symfony, package, composer-php

Current composer

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5",
    "other/bundle": "~1.0"
},
```

When some use other/bundle on dev-develop or another branch he can't install my bundle. How I can allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [stability flags](https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html) are for.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5",
    "other/bundle": "~1.0@dev"
},
```

Comment: get the following error 

requires sulu/sulu ~1.0@dev -> no matching package found.

Comment: You get that error in response to trying what, exactly?

Comment: when require in a root composer file
`sulu/sulu(dev-develop)` and `my_bundle` which has sulu/sulu ~1.0@dev i get the error:  `sulu/sulu ~1.0@dev -> no matching package found`

Comment: is there any or? something like ~1.0||@dev

Comment: Only root-level packages can set stability flag overrides. You root composer.json needs to specify `@dev`

Comment: the root specific currently a specific branch from `sulu/sulu` which is needed. but for this to work i need to set the other bundles requirement to of `sulu/sulu` to `@dev`. but when i do this a root project based on `sulu/sulu` 1.0.* will not work with my bundle because this require @dev.

Comment: Yeah, to me it just sounds like you're trying to do something incompatible with how composer manages versions and stability minimums.